# How can I debug code executed by runInThisContext, in vscode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

In my vscode extension code can be loaded to execute it at runtime using `vm.runInThisContext` (or variants of that like `runInNewContext`). Now I would like to be able to debug that code. Is this possible and if so how?